# Need CSS3 Button Styling

Tags: html, css, button, stylesheet, styling

Ok so I've been given the task of recreating this button

https://s27.postimg.org/7e1upkf4j/BUTTONS.png

Using this section of HTML

```
<a href="#">
  Home <i class="material-icons ico-style">home</i>
</a>
```

I need help I'm so lost on the gradients and whether parts should be box shadows or inset borders etc. Please can you explain the answer

Comment: Could you let me know what is missing in my answer?, so I can adjust and you accept.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion for the gradient part. The *icon* you need to add yourself.

```css
a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  background: linear-gradient(#999,#fff);
  text-decoration: none;
}

a::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 9px;
  top: 9px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background: white;
}

a span {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <span>Home <i class="material-icons ico-style"></i></span>
</a>
```